# Que el token expire solo por inactividad, Jwt Token Framework ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tokens

Tengo un Token realizado con JWT (`IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;`), el cual funciona correctamente y me expira el token a los minutos que le asignó, la cuestión es que quiero que dicho token solo expire si se cumple ciertos minutos de inactividad, ¿como podría llegar  a validar el tiempo de inactividad?.

Clase:

```
public class AuthHelper
{
    private SecurityToken Token;
    private string TokenString;
    public AuthHelper() {
    }   
    public string Auth(tbl_personaModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var TokenString = "";
            if (model.Identificacion != 0 && model.Clave != null)
            {
                var TokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

                var TokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {
                        new Claim( "Correo", model.Identificacion.ToString()),
                        new Claim( "Clave", model.Clave )
                    }),
                    Audience = "https://127.0.0.1",
                    Issuer = "https://127.0.0.1",
                    Expires = now.AddMinutes(5),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secretsecretsecret")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
                };
                SecurityToken Token = TokenHandler.CreateToken(TokenDescriptor);
                TokenString = TokenHandler.WriteToken(Token);
            }
            return TokenString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public bool ValidateToken(string tokenString)
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var Token = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenString);

            //var tokenString2 = tokenHandler.WriteToken(StringToken);
            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            var param = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                ValidIssuer = "https://127.0.0.1",
                ValidAudience = "https://127.0.0.1",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                LifetimeValidator = LifetimeValidator,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secretsecretsecret")),
            };

            var claims = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(tokenString, param, out validatedToken);

            return true;
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenExpiredException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch(SecurityTokenInvalidLifetimeException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // COMPRUEBA LA CADUCIDAD DEL TOKEN
    public bool LifetimeValidator(DateTime? notBefore,
                                  DateTime? expires,
                                  SecurityToken securityToken,
                                  TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        var valid = false;

        if ((expires.HasValue && DateTime.UtcNow < expires)
            && (notBefore.HasValue && DateTime.UtcNow > notBefore))
        { valid = true; }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Por ahora en el parámetro `Expires` manejo el tiempo de vida del token y la sesión, pero busco que si la persona está activa el tiempo de vida del Token y session no se reduzca, ¿Como lo puedo lograr?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes validar el tiempo del token por inactividad esa no es funcion del token,  lo puedes hacer del lado de tu vista con un script, ejemplo inactividad si no se mueve el mouse o si el usuario no hace un llamado al servidor,

ejemplo alerta por 1 min de inactividad.

```js
var timeoutInMiliseconds = 10000;
var timeoutId; 
  
function startTimer() { 
  
    timeoutId =    setTimeout(doInactive, timeoutInMiliseconds);
}
  function resetTimer() { 
window.clearTimeout(timeoutId)
startTimer();
}
  
function doInactive() {
    alert('se cerrara tu sesion');
  //aqui tu codigo para cerrar la sesion 
}
 
function setupTimers () {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
     
    startTimer();
}
 
$(document).ready(function(){
  
     
    setupTimers();
});
```

```html
<div><p> Ejemplo de inactividad 
</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Que es resetTimer?

Comment: Cierto, es una funcion para reiniciar el tiempo de inactividad, ya lo agregue.